# Transform in canvas keeping sprites in correct position when moving

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a complex problem (at least to me) that i have been trying to solve all day, but am not really getting much luck figuring it out.

I have a simple circle and a square drawn in canvas, with a transform that allows me to angle the view.

The problem is, when I click and drag, the objects are not moving correct relative to the change in angle.

This is my draw code :

```
function draw(){

  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  ctx.save();

  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,canvas.width/2,canvas.height/2);  

  ctx.beginPath();

  var x  = (object.x - (camera.x/1)) * camera.scale;
      x *= transform.x;
  var y  = (object.y - (camera.y/1)) * camera.scale;
      y *= transform.y;

  ctx.rect(x-5, y-5,10,10);
  ctx.fill();

  ctx.restore();
  ctx.save();

  ctx.beginPath();

  ctx.setTransform(transform.x,0,0,transform.y,canvas.width/2,canvas.height/2); 

  var x  = (origin.x - (camera.x/1)) * camera.scale;
      x *= transform.x;
  var y  = (origin.y - (camera.y/1)) * camera.scale;
      y *= transform.y;      

  ctx.arc(x,y,radius,0,Math.PI*2);
  ctx.stroke();

  ctx.restore();

  window.requestAnimationFrame(draw); 

}
```

Seeing as it's probably difficult to understand what I am on about without context, aswell as just looking at my code, i provided a working demo here:

**https://jsfiddle.net/h9vf9jd4/**

**Reproduce the behaviour issue:**

1. First click and drag notice the square and circle move together correctly.
2. Now mouse wheel to angle the camera, notice they both angle correctly together.
3. **However**, now at that angle, try and click and drag, and notice a disconnect between the two objects in world space. They no longer move together correctly.

Side note: It seems the circle moves correctly at angled view but not square. But do not know why.

So this is where I am stuck and do not know how to solve it. And am hoping some one is familiar with this stuff to know how to solve it !

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have already set the transform you don't need it again.

Simply remove the following two lines:

```
 var x = (origin.x - (camera.x / 1)) * camera.scale;
 //x *= transform.x;
 var y = (origin.y - (camera.y / 1)) * camera.scale;
 //y *= transform.y;
```

Updated Snippet:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
  radius = 150;
canvas.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}, false);
canvas.addEventListener('wheel', function(e) {

  if (e.deltaY < 0) {
    transform.y += 0.05;
  } else {
    transform.y -= 0.05;
  }
  if (transform.y < 0.7) {
    transform.y = 0.7;
  }
  if (transform.y > 1) {
    transform.y = 1;
  }

}, false);


ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000';
ctx.fillStyle = '#000000';
var origin = {
  'x': 50,
  'y': 30
}

var object = {
  'x': origin.x + radius,
  'y': origin.y - radius
};
var transform = {
  'x': 1,
  'y': 1
}
var camera = {
  'x': 0,
  'y': 0,
  'scale': 1
}


function draw() {

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.save();
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
  ctx.beginPath();

  var x = (object.x - (camera.x / 1)) * camera.scale;
  x *= transform.x;
  var y = (object.y - (camera.y / 1)) * camera.scale;
  y *= transform.y;

  ctx.rect(x - 5, y - 5, 10, 10);
  ctx.fill();

  ctx.restore();
  ctx.save();

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.setTransform(transform.x, 0, 0, transform.y, canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);

  var x = (origin.x - (camera.x / 1)) * camera.scale;
  //x *= transform.x;
  var y = (origin.y - (camera.y / 1)) * camera.scale;
  //y *= transform.y;

  ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.stroke();

  ctx.restore();

  window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);


}

draw();


//element.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) { cameraAngle(e,this);}, false);
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
  moveCamera(e, this);
}, false);

function moveCamera(evt, el) {
  var x = evt.offsetX,
    y = evt.offsetY;


  function update(e) {
    var difx = x - e.offsetX,
      dify = y - e.offsetY;

    x = e.offsetX;
    y = e.offsetY;

    camera.x += difx;
    camera.y += dify;
  }

  function clear() {
    el.removeEventListener('mousemove', update, false);
    this.removeEventListener('mouseup', clear, false);
  }
  el.addEventListener('mousemove', update, false);
  document.body.addEventListener('mouseup', clear, false);
}
```

```css
#canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just an FYI to readers, after refactoring the code it turns out this solution is unusable when adding camera movements, for static content its a perfect solution. But i have posted a new question with the added complication that i am struggling to solve at the moment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34760386/moving-camera-from-mouse-input-with-2d-transformation-applied-to-canvas